# Freeform "Field Options" Multi-List List type not working

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am trying to set up a form using Freeform Pro and when I try to use a "Select" field I am not able to click on any of the List type options. If I click on "Load from Channel Field" with the proper Channel Field selected I receive an error that says:

"You must choose some data option for multi-rows in order for this field type to work."

It seems as though it is not letting me actually select a list type.

I re-installed it, but it still didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that the themes are properly installed? Sounds like a JavaScript error.